# Loop x words and move 1 position

Tags: java

I want to loop through a String and return an array of strings that are the same length of the first argument. For example if I call `search("one two three", "one two three four five")`, it should return `["one two three", "two three four", "three four five"]`
I've tried

```
        int numQualified = (int) (Math.floor(searchInWords.length / searchForWords.length) + 1);
        String[] qualified = new String[numQualified];
        for (int i = 0; i < numQualified; i++) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < searchForWords.length; j++) {
                if (searchInWords.length <= (searchForWords.length * i) + j) break;
                builder.append(searchInWords[(searchForWords.length * i) + j]).append(" ");
            }
            qualified[i] = builder.toString().trim();
            System.out.println("t: " + qualified[i]);
        }
```

However, it doesn't really work. If I input "one two three four five," I get `[{four five}, {one two three}]` instead of `["one two three", "two three four", "three four five"]`.

Comment: I don't understand your example.  You said you were going to return strings that are the same length as the first argument.  In your example, the first argument is "one two".  You said you wanted it to return the strings "one two three", "two three four", and "three four five".  But none of those strings appear to be the same length as "one two".  Can you clarify what this function is supposed to do?

Comment: My bad, I edited the problem.

Comment: Is `searchInWords` "one two three" or is it "one two three four five" ?

Comment: @Abra searchInWords is "one two three four five" searchForWords is "one two three"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are multiple issues here.  I think they all result from some ambiguity about whether you want to allow overlapping answers.  In your example, you listed both "one two three" and "two three four" as strings you want to find, so it appears that you do want to include overlapping strings.  However, the code that you've shown appears to have been written with the assumption that you do not want overlapping answers, and I think that is the cause of the issues.

First, the calculation for `numQualified` appears wrong.  Say, for example, that `searchInWords` contained 100 words, and `searchForWords` contained 2 words.  Your calculation for `numQualified` would yield 100/2 + 1 = 51.  But, aren't there really 99 different two-word-strings to be found in this case?

Second, inside your for loop, you use `(searchForWords.length * i) + j` to calculate the index of a string that you are examining.  This formula assumes non-overlapping strings, so it isn't going to get the results you want.  In your example, `searchForWords.length` is 3, so when i is 0, this formula will calculate indices 0,1,2.  When i is 1, it would calculate indices 3,4,5.  When i is 2, it would be 6,7,8.  Note that these sequences do not overlap.

I hope these observations help you get the results you are looking for.